# elasticsearch query field names are case-insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

## method-1

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "TimeStamp": {
                "value": "2022-08-17T00:10:11.746+0800"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## method-2

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "timeStamp": {
                "value": "2022-08-17T00:10:11.746+0800"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want TimeStamp to be case-insensitive so that I can query the same result.

Thank you for your answer!！！！！

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field of [type `alias`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-alias.html) that references the real timestamp field in your mapping:

```
PUT my-index/_mapping
{
   "mappings": {
      "timeStamp": {
        "type": "alias",
        "path": "TimeStamp" 
      }
   }
}
```